# Type name in brackets

Tags: java, collections, casting

Not sure what I should call it but here's a piece of code I've come across.

```
ArrayList<String> c1 = (ArrayList<String>)(Collection1.clone());
c1.addAll(collection2);
```

What do these two brackets `(ArrayList<String>)(Collection1.clone())` do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`(ArrayList<string>)(Collection1.clone());` is same as

`(ArrayList<string>) Collection1.clone();`

You are casting the returned object from `Collection1.clone()` to `ArrayList<String>`. Second set of `()`, around  `Collection1.clone()` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This is called casting i.e. the result of `Collection1.clone()` is being cast to type `ArrayList<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ArrayList<string>)(Collection1.clone())

 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^
 Type of Cast           Object to cast
```

This is explicit type casting. First bracket contains the type to be cast and in second bracket contains the actual Object to be cast.

Comment: Does it mean that Collection1 is "converted" into ArrayList (I understand that ArrayList is a class of Collection)?

Comment: yap, `Collection1` object will be converted to `ArrayList` type object.